# Query to calculate standings and compare head-to-head for tie-breaking

Tags: sql-server

Need a query to order team standings for a soccer league that uses a points system as well as a head-to-head comparison when points are tied.

A given league uses a variety of formulas for computing points and ordering teams.  Average points are calculated as number of points divided by number of games with 3 points for a win, 1 for a tie and 0 for a loss.  After points, averages for goal differential, most wins, etc. are used.  However; if all of those are tied, we need a way to order the standings by head-to-head results. I have a query for the points calculations and it works fine, but no real clue how to incorporate the head-to-head component.

[image: standings needed for MS SQM query]

**ADDED for clarity, after initial posting.**
Currently, the database consists of a schedule table with that includes a TABLE for SCHEDULES that has HTEAM, VTEAM, HRUNS, VRUNS, HFOREFIT and VFORFEIT as teams can dual forfeit as well.  From that SCHEDULES table a view is constructed to calculate the points see below:

```
FROM            (SELECT        SCHEDULE.GNUM, SCHEDULE.DIVISION, SCHEDULE.HTEAM AS TeamID, CASE WHEN (Schedule.HRuns > Schedule.VRuns) OR
                                                    (Schedule.VForfeit = 1) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS [W], CASE WHEN (Schedule.HRuns < Schedule.VRuns) AND (Schedule.VForfeit = 0) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS [L], 
                                                    CASE WHEN Schedule.HRuns = Schedule.VRuns THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS [D], CASE WHEN Schedule.Hforfeit = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS [Forfeit], Schedule.HRuns AS [GF], Schedule.VRuns AS [GA], 
                                                    Schedule.HRuns - Schedule.VRuns AS [GD], Teams.TCode, Teams.Team
                          FROM            SCHEDULE INNER JOIN
                                                    TEAMS ON SCHEDULE.HTEAM = TEAMS.TCODE
                          WHERE        (SCHEDULE.PLAYED <> 0) AND (SCHEDULE.HFORFEIT = 0)) AS T
UNION
SELECT        *, CASE WHEN GD > 3 THEN 3 WHEN GD < - 3 THEN - 3 ELSE GD END AS [MaxGD], CASE WHEN W = 1 THEN 3 WHEN D = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS [Points]
FROM            (SELECT        SCHEDULE.GNUM, SCHEDULE.DIVISION, SCHEDULE.VTEAM AS TeamID, CASE WHEN (Schedule.HRuns < Schedule.VRuns) OR
                                                    (Schedule.HForfeit = 1) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS [W], CASE WHEN (Schedule.HRuns > Schedule.VRuns) AND (Schedule.HForfeit = 0) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS [L], 
                                                    CASE WHEN Schedule.HRuns = Schedule.VRuns THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS [D], CASE WHEN Schedule.Hforfeit = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS [Forfeit], Schedule.VRuns AS [GF], Schedule.HRuns AS [GA], 
                                                    Schedule.VRuns - Schedule.HRuns AS [GD], Teams.TCode, Teams.Team
                          FROM            SCHEDULE, teams
                          WHERE        (Schedule.VTeam = Teams.TCode) AND (SCHEDULE.PLAYED <> 0) AND (SCHEDULE.VFORFEIT = 0)) AS T
UNION
SELECT        *, CASE WHEN GD > 3 THEN 3 WHEN GD < - 3 THEN - 3 ELSE GD END AS [MaxGD], 0 AS [Points]
FROM            (SELECT        Schedule.gnum, Schedule.Division, Schedule.HTeam AS TeamID, 0 AS [W], 1 AS [L], 0 AS [D], 1 AS [Forfeit], 0 AS [GF], 3 AS [GA], - 3 AS [GD], Teams.TCode, Teams.Team
                          FROM            Schedule, Teams
                          WHERE        Schedule.HTeam = Teams.TCode AND Schedule.Played <> 0 AND HForfeit = 1) AS T
UNION
SELECT        *, CASE WHEN GD > 3 THEN 3 WHEN GD < - 3 THEN - 3 ELSE GD END AS [MaxGD], 0 AS [Points]
FROM            (SELECT        Schedule.gnum, Schedule.Division, Schedule.VTeam AS TeamID, 0 AS [W], 1 AS [L], 0 AS [D], 1 AS [Forfeit], 0 AS [GF], 3 AS [GA], - 3 AS [GD], Teams.TCode, Teams.Team
                          FROM            Schedule, Teams
                          WHERE        Schedule.VTeam = Teams.TCode AND Schedule.Played <> 0 AND VForfeit = 1) AS T
```

The POINTS view then is used to generate a standings view which displays the proper order except for calculating the head to head.

Here is a fiddle for a sample division where three teams are tied on points (DSC2004MC2, NMM2004MC1, and SHS2004MC1) The SHS2004MC1 team beat the other two so they would be next in line and then the remaining two teams would be compared for their head-to-head that NMM2004MC1 won.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/156216/5

Answer (score 0):

Try this below-

> Some columns like AvgPts,AvgGDS are not calculated here as logic is not clear. But you can calculate them as all necessary information in now available for calculation.

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT *,
    CAST(SUBSTRING(Goal,0,CHARINDEX('-',Goal,0)) AS INT) T1_Goal,
    CAST(SUBSTRING(Goal,CHARINDEX('-',Goal,0)+1,LEN(Goal)) AS INT) T2_Goal,
    CASE 
        WHEN CAST(SUBSTRING(Goal,0,CHARINDEX('-',Goal,0)) AS INT) = CAST(SUBSTRING(Goal,CHARINDEX('-',Goal,0)+1,LEN(Goal)) AS INT) THEN 1
        WHEN CAST(SUBSTRING(Goal,0,CHARINDEX('-',Goal,0)) AS INT)  > CAST(SUBSTRING(Goal,CHARINDEX('-',Goal,0)+1,LEN(Goal)) AS INT) THEN 3
        ELSE 0
    END T1_Point,
    CASE 
        WHEN CAST(SUBSTRING(Goal,0,CHARINDEX('-',Goal,0)) AS INT) = CAST(SUBSTRING(Goal,CHARINDEX('-',Goal,0)+1,LEN(Goal)) AS INT) THEN 1
        WHEN CAST(SUBSTRING(Goal,0,CHARINDEX('-',Goal,0)) AS INT) < CAST(SUBSTRING(Goal,CHARINDEX('-',Goal,0)+1,LEN(Goal)) AS INT) THEN 3
        ELSE 0
    END T2_Point,   
    CASE 
        WHEN CAST(SUBSTRING(Goal,0,CHARINDEX('-',Goal,0)) AS INT)  > CAST(SUBSTRING(Goal,CHARINDEX('-',Goal,0)+1,LEN(Goal)) AS INT) THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END T1_Win,
    CASE 
        WHEN CAST(SUBSTRING(Goal,0,CHARINDEX('-',Goal,0)) AS INT)  = CAST(SUBSTRING(Goal,CHARINDEX('-',Goal,0)+1,LEN(Goal)) AS INT) THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END T1_Draw,
    CASE 
        WHEN CAST(SUBSTRING(Goal,0,CHARINDEX('-',Goal,0)) AS INT) < CAST(SUBSTRING(Goal,CHARINDEX('-',Goal,0)+1,LEN(Goal)) AS INT) THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END T1_Lose,    
    CASE 
        WHEN CAST(SUBSTRING(Goal,0,CHARINDEX('-',Goal,0)) AS INT)  < CAST(SUBSTRING(Goal,CHARINDEX('-',Goal,0)+1,LEN(Goal)) AS INT) THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END T2_Win,
    CASE 
        WHEN CAST(SUBSTRING(Goal,0,CHARINDEX('-',Goal,0)) AS INT)  = CAST(SUBSTRING(Goal,CHARINDEX('-',Goal,0)+1,LEN(Goal)) AS INT) THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END T2_Draw,
    CASE 
        WHEN CAST(SUBSTRING(Goal,0,CHARINDEX('-',Goal,0)) AS INT) > CAST(SUBSTRING(Goal,CHARINDEX('-',Goal,0)+1,LEN(Goal)) AS INT) THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END T2_Lose
    FROM Match
)

SELECT A.Team_Name,
COUNT(*) Match_payed,
SUM(A.Win) Wins,
SUM(A.Lose) Loses,
SUM(A.Draw) Draws,
SUM(A.Goal_Own) GF,
SUM(A.Goal_Away) GA,
SUM(A.Goal_Own) - SUM(A.Goal_Away) GD,
SUM(A.Point) Points
FROM (
    SELECT A.T1 Team_Name,
    A.T1_Goal Goal_Own,A.T2_Goal Goal_Away,A.T1_Point Point,
    A.T1_Win Win, A.T1_Draw Draw, A.T1_Lose Lose
    FROM CTE A

    UNION ALL

    SELECT A.T2 Team_Name,
    A.T2_Goal Goal_Own,A.T1_Goal Goal_Away,A.T2_Point Point,
    A.T2_Win,A.T2_Draw,A.T2_Lose
    FROM CTE A
)A
GROUP BY A.Team_Name
ORDER BY SUM(A.Point) DESC
```

Output will be like-

```
Team_Name   Match_payed  Wins   Loses   Draws   GF  GA  GD  Points
Team D      2            2      0       0       5   0   5   6
Team C      2            1      1       0       4   1   3   3
Team B      2            0      2       0       0   8   -8  0
```

Comment: Perhaps I should have been more clear as it appears you took my record of game score to be a text 4 - 0 instead of an actual record.  I have edited the question above to be more clear.  I am not sure I follow where in your code the head-to-head comparison is done?

Comment: what do you mean by actual record? is that 2 separate field of INT value?

Comment: Yes, the actual scores are recorded in the schedule.hruns, schedule.vruns both INT.  Also forfeits are compared and computed as losses with the added possibility of dual forfeits.

Comment: If they are separate int field, its much easier. Either post some actual sample data or you can use the logic i have shown. Thus will decrease the substring and casting cost.